# Perform XNOR on 2 integers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, int

> XNOR operation should be performed on the two integer values (1101011 XNOR 1010101) and should return 1000001.

```
int a = 1101011;
int b = 1010101;

int res = 0;
res = ~(a ^ b);

cout << res;
```

> This outputs: -2073959.

I'm very new to programming, and any help regarding where I have gone wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Is not it the bitwise AND operator?

Comment: Do you know how to read hexadecimal?  You can display that with `std::cout << std::hex << res;`, if you put `#include <iomanip>` at the top of your file.  Each hex digit encodes 4 binary digits, so it's easier to see how the result relates to the inputs.  What you're doing now puts decimal numbers `1101011` and `1010101` into `a` and `b` - *not* the binary numbers you intend.  `a` and `b` are `int`s, so have 32 bits - way more than you want involved in your XNOR operation: the higher bits end up getting set to 1 by the XNOR, and the high bit being on means the result is negative.

Comment: You should always do bitwise operations on unsigned integers. And you shouldn't confuse a number written in decimal using just zeros and ones with a binary number. ('11' in the decimal system is eleven, '11' in the binary system is three - binary '1101011' is one hundred and seven.)

Answer (score 1):

You've gone wrong in assuming that `1101011` and `10101010` are decimal values.  They are, in fact, binary.

AFAIK, C++ does not support binary assignment; if it did, you would typically indicate this with `01101011` or `01101011b`. Since it doesn't, you instead need to treat these as Hex to handle them most easily.

```
01101011 = 0x6b
10101010 = 0xaa
```

If you use these values in your code (in other words, `int a = 0x6b`, etc) and then repeat your operation, you will perform the operation correctly.  The way you are currently printing the result, it will be printed in decimal, which must then be converted to binary (if that's desired), though someone has offered a comment to assist you to get the output into Hex.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you suppose that the variables `a` and `b` are initialized by binary values. However these

```
1101011
1010101
```

are decimal integer literals.

If you want to use binary literals and your compiler supports them then you should write

```
int a = 0b1101011;
int b = 0b1010101;
```

Otherwise you can use the decimal integer literals but you have to apply operations to them that suitable for decimal values that to get a new decimal value that looks like a binary value.

Also it seems the operation `XNOR`  looks like the binary bitwise AND operator.

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows how you can get the desired rtesult.

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream & binary( int x, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    if ( x ) binary( ( unsigned int )x >> 1 );
    os << ( x & 1 );

    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    int a = 0b1101011;
    int b = 0b1010101;

    int res = a & b;

    binary( a ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "XNOR" << std::endl;
    binary( b ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "========" << std::endl;
    binary( res ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
01101011
XNOR
01010101
========
01000001
```

If you want to deal with a decimal representation of binary values then you can write a separate function for the operation `XNOR` as for example

```
#include <iostream>

int xnor( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;
    unsigned int n = 1;
    unsigned int res = 0;

    while ( a and b )
    {
        res = res + n * ( a % Base and b % Base );
        n *= Base;
        a /= Base;
        b /= Base;
    }

    return res;
}

int main() 
{
    unsigned int a = 1101011;
    unsigned int b = 1010101;

    int res = xnor( a, b );

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "XNOR" << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "========" << std::endl;
    std::cout << res << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1101011
XNOR
1010101
========
1000001
```

Take into account that your approach in any case is wrong.

This expression

```
res = ~(a ^ b);
```

sets most significant bits to `1` if they were equal to `0` for the both variables `a` and `b`. So for positive numbers you will always get a negative number because the sign bit will be set to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you want to do this:

```
  1101011 ^
  1010101
  -------
= 0111110

  0111110 ~
  -------
= 1000001
```

And you actually do this:

```
  00000000000100001100110011010011 ^  // int  1101011
  00000000000011110110100110110101    // int  1010101
  --------------------------------
= 00000000000111111010010101100110    // int  2073958

  00000000000111111010010101100110 ~  // int  2073958
  --------------------------------
= 11111111111000000101101010011001    // int -2073959
```

So instead of:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 1101011;
    int b = 1010101;

    int res = 0;
    int ans = 0;
    ans = (a ^ b);
    res = ~ans;

    std::cout << a << '\n';
    std::cout << b << '\n';
    std::cout << ans << '\n';
    std::cout << res << '\n';
}
```

Use `#include <bitset>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    int a = 107;
    int b = 85;

    int res = 0;
    int ans = 0;
    ans = (a ^ b);
    res = ~ans;

    std::cout << std::bitset<7>(a) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::bitset<7>(b) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::bitset<7>(res) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::bitset<7>(res) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For inputs of ISO standard c++ binary, octal, decimal, and hex see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

To display output as hex, decimal, binary, and then decimal again:

```
unsigned int y = 17 ;
std::cout << std::hex << y << '\n' ;
std::cout << std::dec << y << '\n' ;
std::bitset<32>x(y) ; 
std::cout << x << '\n' ; 
std::cout << y << endl ;
```

The "32" sets the length of the binary output, setting it too low for the contained value will display the least significant digits, `bitset<8>M(515); cout << M << endl ;` will display 00000011. Setting the length larger than the input type will pad the most significant digits with '0's. By default `std::cout` does not handle type char as numerical and will display the corresponding character, to display a char as its numerical code you must mess around casting it into an [`unsigned`] `short`, `int`, or `long`. However `std::bitset` will treat a `char` as raw bits, the same as it does for other integer types.

Use `unsigned` integer types, these could be `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, or `long long`. The exact byte lengths of each may vary based on the cpu and operating system, use `sizeof(x)` to print the length of item x in units of `char`. [`char` == 8 bits in 99% of modern implementations] (Most common modern x86_64 will have respective integer type lengths of 1, 2, 4, 8, 8 or 1, 2, 4, 4, 8 bytes. 128bit/16byte c++ integer type is not yet standardized on x86_64, there is a non-standard 128bit integer type but it is trouble to work with, there are also libraries that allow the use of arbitrary length numbers.)

If comparing two sizes eg `short` with `long`, the `short` may be implicitly cast to a `long` and padded with zeros for the comparison; I would test this case before relying on it.

The logic gate situation: XNOR[NXOR] is not equivalent to AND. The choice of which you really want is on you.

false AND false == false ; true AND true == true ; false AND true == false

false XNOR false == true ; true XNOR true == true ; false XNOR true == false

`signed` types can be compared as they are also a string of binary, but the output will not be intuitive with all possible inputs and you should have a very strong reason for doing it, like experimenting with math conjectures regarding twos compliment numerals.